# Can't get cookie free domain working for my WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, plesk

I'm trying hard to get my cookie free domain working for my WordPress installation. I've followed a lot of tutorials but I still get no content over the new cookie free subdomain. These are my steps:

1. I've created a new subdomain `static.my-page.de` in my Plesk panel and set my `wp-content` folder as document root for this subdomain
2. I've logged in into my domain provider account, added a subdomain under my domain `my-page.de` and created an A-Record to my Plesk server (entered the IP like for all other subdomains)
3. After this I've enabled SSL for the new subdomain and selected my wildcard certificate

After this I've did the needed changes in my WordPress `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://static.my-page.de' );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'https://www.my-page.de' );
```

Finally I've changed all my `post_content` entries in my DB to my new static subdomain.

Normally I should get all my `wp-content` folder content via my static non-cookie subdomain but the page design is completely broken and the console full of errors like this:

```
(index):1830 GET https://static.my-page.de/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/js/um-members.min.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

What did I do wrong? I've gone over everything 100 times and no luck...

Comment: The `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` message would normally indicate a problem in DNS resolution.  Are you sure you added the proper DNS record to the correct name server?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Well, I did everything described above but not more. I only added an A-Record at my domain provider to my Plesk server. Thats all. Did I missed something?

Comment: The only thing I have to go on is the DNS error from your post.  If that is the only kind of error, then I assume the configurations you made are working.  The error indicates there is either an issue with your local DNS resolver (check contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`) or with your configured DNS name server (use tools like `dig`, `host`, or `nslookup` to test domain resolution).